# Zoom In/Out on background image when resizing the browser page

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently developing the footer of a web page in HTML / CSS. This footer will contain a lot of elements (address, links, buttons, ...) and it must, therefore, be responsive. Consequently, on a desktop version, we have all the footer's elements on a row and, then on mobile we have all the footer's elements on a column (as the following images show you);

My goal is to get the result below on a widescreen (desktop):

[image: Desktop Footer]

And here is the result I want to achieve on a mobile screen:

[image: Mobile Footer]

As you can see, we must have a zoom effect when resizing the page of a browser or when we pass on a smartphone screen. I have a lot of elements to insert in the footer so the image must be zoomed to integrate them all.

Here is the code I have done so far.

```css
.footer {
  height: 639px;
  background: url("https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2020/07/11/200711012945662645.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer"></div>
```

The result is almost what I want but the problem is that **the height** of the footer does not change, and therefore I do not have enough space to put all my elements in the footer in the mobile version.

Thank you :)

Comment: Well then don’t specify a height, so that the footer can take the height its children need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { //480px is breakpoint you can adjust according to your need

    .footer {
      height: auto;
      background: url("https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2020/07/11/200711012945662645.png");
      background-position: center top; //adjust according to you need
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      padding-top: 3rem; //adjust according to your need
      padding-bottom:3rem; //adjust according to your need
      padding-left:inherit;
      padding-right:inherit;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `height: auto`, `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` in a media query for phone. You may have to experiment with the padding values a few times to make it look good. Also change the `background-position` so the curve can be seen on mobile phones. It will look something like this.

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px){
.footer{
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-position: center top; 
 }
}
```